# System verilog: choose module input or output at compile time

Tags: system-verilog

I have an issue for a system-verilog project. I simulate using Questasim, but this is more a language-related question, I actually have not been able to find any answer in more than 2 weeks of studying.

I have a collection of many (~1000s) *almost identical* modules, repeated and connected one another. This module is parametrized with an `ID`. Inside the module, some actions are performed depending on the value of this `ID` and everything looks working as expected.

The reason why these modules are not exactly identical is that, depending on the ID, some signals to and from the modules swap. What I mean is that, in pseudo code, I would like to have something like:

```
module test #(
    ID = 0
  )  (
    ...
    if(ID == 0) input wire A
    else if(ID == 1) output wire A
    ...

    ...

endmodule
```

does systemverilog support, in any way, something like this? I can work around this problem using a verilog generating script, but that is not so maintainable in my experience.

This is actually a semplification, I truly have ~10s of signal and they change from input to output in almost any possible way, therefore manual writing is hardly possible.

I know it may be possible to just work with `inout` and do everything inside, but at compile time I do know exactly what is an input and what is an output for every ID, therefore this solution does not look elegant at all to me.

Comment: Does this need to be synthesizable?

Comment: I actually wish it were synthesizable. Let's say a non-sinthesizable version can help me make some calculations but, at the end of the day, I would like to synthesize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that there is a way to redefine port direction this way. You can try to work with `inout` directions, as in the following example:

```
module mod#(P=1)(inout a,b,c);
  if (P) begin
    assign c = a | b;
  end
  else begin
   assign a = b | c;
  end
endmodule

module top;
  wire a,b,c,d, e, f;
  mod#(1) mod1(a,b,e);
  mod#(0) mod2(f,c,d);
endmodule
```

Comment: I had this in mind, but I hoped I could do something better to skip inouts|. Anyway thank you, this of course works delightfully. If no better answers are given within this week I will mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to obtain is instantiate two different modules with completely different behavior (depending on ID parameter).

It would be cleaner using different modules for different purposes:

```
module test_ID0 (...)
  input wire A
  ...
endmodule

module test_ID1 (...)
  output wire A
  ...
endmodule
```

Shared parts of both modules could be encapsulated in lower level module.

In your top level, assuming you are using the `generate` construct, you can use the genvar to select module instantiation, not only as parameter:

```
module top
  ...
  generate
    for(genvar i=0; i<N; i++) begin
      if((i%2)==0) begin
        test_ID0 u_testID0(.a(a[i]),.b(b[i]),.c(c[i]));
      end
      else begin
        test_ID1 u_testID1(.a(a[i]),.b(b[i]),.c(c[i]));
      end
    end
  endgenerate
  ...
endmodule
```